# Javascript best way to extract particular text from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `xyz-12-1`. Numbers can be anything , or even the text can be anything. I'm trying to extract the numbers `12` and `1` in the string.
I tried and succeeded with the following code.

```js
var test = "node-23-1";
test = test.replace(test.substring(0, test.indexOf("-") + 1), ""); //remove the string part
var node1 = test.substring(0, test.indexOf("-")); //get first number
var node2 = test.substring(test.indexOf("-") + 1, test.length); //get second number
alert(node1);
alert(node2);
```

I feel this is too much code.
It is working fine. But is there a more readable , more efficient way to do the same ?

Comment: `'xyz-12-1'.split('-')[1]`  or `'xyz-12-1'.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/)[1]`

Comment: Perfect. Please write it as answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** or **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**

```js
var res = 'xyz-12-1'.split('-'); // get values by index 1 and 2
var res1 = 'xyz-12-1'.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/); // get values by index 1 and 2

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res) +'\n'+ JSON.stringify(res1) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the split function.

like this `'xyz-12-1'.split('-')[1]` and `'xyz-12-1'.split('-')[2]`